# Cannot insert a div element that has class attribute when using appendchild. Is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

So i have 5 tag elements but there is 3 tag elements that cause me problems. I have created these tags with document.createElement()

- form tag

  - input type=hidden
  - input type=hidden
  - div tag

    - input tag file

my code:

```
let form = document.createElement('form')
let div = document.createElement('div')
```

when i do `form.appendChild(div)` it  works but when i add a class attribute to div i see no div inside the form after doing a console.log, even if i add the class attribute after

Comment: May you create a stacksnippet with a [mcve] in it? So we don't have to imagine what you're talking about.

Comment: The classname for the div was 'fallback'. <div class="fallback"></div>. As the form was a Dropzone.js form, when i add a div with the classname 'fallback' it's removed it automatically that's why there were no div element. I finally resolve my problem! thank's for your support!